# Sending Image from one Activity to another fails

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

I am trying to integrate google plus login to get user details such as name, email and his profile pic.

Now Using the below code I'm trying to get his name,email and profile pic if I use it in the same activity I'm getting his profile pic too

**Login.Java**

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    // We've resolved any connection errors. mGoogleApiClient can be used to
    // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
    // Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();
}

private void getProfileInformation() {

    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
        String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
        Toast.makeText(this, personPhotoUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        //new GetProfileImage(urImageView).execute(personPhotoUrl);
        // Create the bundle
        new GetProfileImage().execute(personPhotoUrl);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        // Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
        bundle.putString("Google", "Logged in using Google Account");
        bundle.putString("GoogleUsername", currentPerson.getDisplayName());
        bundle.putString("GoogleEmail", email);
        if(resultBmp!=null) {

            i.putExtra("GoogleProfileImage", resultBmp);
        }
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private class GetProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {

            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        resultBmp = result;
        //bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API, PlusOptions.builder().build())
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getStringExtra("Google") != null){ 

        // 1. get passed intent 
        // 2. get message value from intent
        String userName = intent.getStringExtra("GoogleUsername");
        String email = intent.getStringExtra("GoogleEmail");
        if(intent.getStringExtra("Google").equals("Logged in using Google Account")){

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).setText(userName);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtemail)).setText(email);

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("GoogleProfileImage");
            //Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("GooglePic");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Debug","Connection failed");
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Login.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    //super.onConnectionFailed(result);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Debug","Connected");
    //super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

If I try to send this image to next activity it dosent show me the pic at the first login. If I login for the second time or I resume the app it displays the pic.

Can anyone say me where am I going wrong in my MainActivity?

Comment: i think better way is to pass imageview  path and get image from path in MainActivity,passing image bitamp requires a lot of memory.

Comment: is there any reason to pass image bitmap instead path ?

Comment: There is nothing like that.I would to just show user his profile pic after he logins just as gmail and youtube with navigation drawer.

Comment: I think you have to use AndroidQuery library for image loading in async manner and also provide option cache image so when you in Login activity image will be loaded from url and cached now when you pass only url or path it will be directly loaded from cached area instead from url source.

Answer (score 0):

try like this way,

Convert it to a Byte array before you add it to the intent, send it out, and decode.

//Convert to byte array

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
in1.putExtra("image",byteArray);
```

Then in Activity 2:

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: Creating byte array ia not a correct solution because it will take time to create bytes from image which can result delay in showing next screen.  You can use parcelable interface while you are passing objects through Intent. Please read more about parcelable from developer.android.com

Comment: @Moradiya- Thanks for your help..Even I tried this way but didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Make your Bitmap references Static as static variables can be accessed from another  activity.

Answer (score 0):

I thing your problem is that:

Loading an image take time so when the activity start for the first time the image didn't load yet, that's way u see the image only at the second time when it already loaded.

try to use an asyncTask or any other background process to load the image.

If you use normal thread don't forget to call "runOnUIthread" when set the image to view.
If you already use background process to load the image set a call back to call when the process is done.